# Illegal Self Reference in creation of class

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java, my code is giving me the error "Illegal Self reference" in the lines below on Charmander/Squirtle/Bulbasaur.moveList

```
static Pokemon Charmander = new Pokemon("Fire", "Charmander", 25, Charmander.moveList);
static Pokemon Squirtle = new Pokemon("Water", "Squirtle", 25, Squirtle.moveList);
static Pokemon Bulbasaur = new Pokemon("Grass", "Bulbasaur ", 25, Bulbasaur.moveList);
```

Here is my code

```
public class Pokemon_Builder {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Move_Builder mb = new Move_Builder();
    Charmander.moveList.add(mb.Ember);
    Charmander.moveList.add(mb.Scratch);
    Charmander.moveList.add(mb.Willowisp);
    Charmander.moveList.add(mb.Recover);
    Squirtle.moveList.add(mb.Bubble);
    Squirtle.moveList.add(mb.Tackle);
    Squirtle.moveList.add(mb.Powdersnow);
    Squirtle.moveList.add(mb.Recover);
    Bulbasaur.moveList.add(mb.Vinewhip);
    Bulbasaur.moveList.add(mb.Poisonpowder);
    Bulbasaur.moveList.add(mb.Tackle);
    Bulbasaur.moveList.add(mb.Recover);
    System.out.println(Charmander.moveList.size());
  }
  static Pokemon Charmander = new Pokemon("Fire", "Charmander", 25, Charmander.moveList);
  static Pokemon Squirtle = new Pokemon("Water", "Squirtle", 25, Squirtle.moveList);
  static Pokemon Bulbasaur = new Pokemon("Grass", "Bulbasaur ", 25, Bulbasaur.moveList);
}
```

And here is the code for the Pokemon Class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pokemon{
  String type;
  String name;
  int health;
  List<Move> moveList = new LinkedList<Move>();
  public Pokemon(String type, String name, int health, LinkedList moveList) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.moveList = moveList;
  }
  public void getInfo (){
    System.out.println("Pokemon Name "+ this.name);
    System.out.println("Your Pokemon's type "+ this.type);
    System.out.println("Your Pokemon's health "+ this.health);
  }
  public void addMove(Move toAdd){
    if (moveList.size() < 5){
        moveList.add(toAdd);
    }
    else{System.out.println("Can't learn any more moves!");
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? You are trying to pass a field of `Charmander` to the constructor which is creating `Charmander`.

Comment: Would you mind showing your pokemon constructor?

Comment: I recommend grabbing a beginners book on java and working your way through it to learn: 
what objects are; what the static keyword means; what are setters and getters; what the `new` keyword means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class Pokemon_builder you create 3 pokemon, while creating those pokemon you provide a moveList. Those movelists are created when the pokemon is created. Meaning what you now try to do is pass a field of a pokemon to the constructor for that pokemon.

Comment: So what should I do

Comment: @Daddy You already initialize moveList as a new LinkedList when an instance of the class is created, so what you can do is just remove the moveList from the constructor and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

As your Pokemon object is instantiating itself the the static member object creation runs before the constructors do. You are trying to create an object called Charmander and pass into Charmander's constructor a reference to a static "movelist" object within Charmander. You are doing this BEFORE Charmander has completed its object instantiation process. Thus you are trying to create an object that needs a reference within itself to "construct" itself.

Comment: So What Should I Do

Comment: You are essentially already doing it. You create a "new" movelist as a member variable in each Pokemon object. You don't need to pass another movelist into the constructor. Just remove the movelist parameter from the constructor.